# Log File Monitoring and Output Specific Format

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a log file that shows the following information in it.  It also has lines with 'logging out'.  I need to filter out the logged out lines from the logged in ones.  Then strip specific information from the logging in lines.

```
YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MM.SS: 'IPv4address backendidnumber:Username(DBID#)' logged in
```

IPv4address can change.  Backendidnumber is a 17 digit number that never changes.  DBID# can be 1 and grows.  This number changes for the username as well since it is a number associated with the session.

I currently have the following code that monitors a log file from a set of downloaded logs every minute.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tail -n0 -F all-logins.log | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "logged in"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
           curl -sfSL -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"content\":\"$line\"}" "webhook html url here"
        fi
done
```

I don't want the full line posted.  I just want the message to display this

```
  Username logged in at HH:MM on MM.DD.YYYY
```

Also the username can have spaces in the name as well as numbers

Comment: You should add an example of logins.log line and show your tries and what goes wrong

Comment: Nothing is wrong currently.  It works as is.  That is the issue.  I don't know how to change it to output only the Username and reformat the time and date.

Comment: Please see examples on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).